# Creating a shared folder in windows using ansible playbook

Tags: automation, ansible, devops

I'm trying to create an ansible playbook to create a shared folder in windows. So I want to get the target windows hostname automatically while executing the playbook and create the folder as filedownload path,
I'm struggle with getting the hostname automatically during folder creation.

```
---
# creating share_folder for file download

- name: create share folder for file download
  win_share: 
    name: fileFileDownloadPath
    description: share folder for file download
    path: C:\(target windows hostname should come here)\{{FileDownloadPath}}
    full: Administrator
```

Comment: Where did you store the targets hostnames ? Are they in your inventory ? In a specific group ? In file you need to load ? Passed on the command line when launching the playbook ? Asked interactively by vars_prompt ? etc.

Comment: i want to get the host name of the windows machine dynamically. need to figure out the way

Comment: Get the name of which widows machine ? Your question is not clear at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ansible_hostname or inventory_hostname fact

```
path: C:\{{ansible_hostname }}\{{FileDownloadPath}}
or 
path: C:\{{inventory_hostname }}\{{FileDownloadPath}}
```